# ¿Como quitar el "Ningún archivo selec." del input? - HTML

Tags: html, input

Encuentro molesta la descripción de "Ningún archivo selec.", por lo que quiero quitarla de la visualización, pero no se cómo.

Primero me di cuenta que sirve, para saber que el archivo se ha seleccionado, pero su posición es demasiado incómoda para mi. Por lo que quería que aparéese en el botón del input, en vez de a la derecha de este. Si no se ha seleccionado el archivo, que diga "Seleccionar archivo" como es default, pero una vez seleccionado, que muestre el nombre del archivo en el boton.

He intentado ocultar esa descripción, pero termino haciendo desaparecer el input entero si hago uso de CSS `display: none`. Alguna idea ?

EDIT**

Acabo de notar que el texto, es parte del `width` del botón, por lo que hay que tomar eso en cuenta además... acá estos 3 inputs tienen el mismo width.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<form action="subirArchivo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Subir un Archivo:<br><br>
  <input type="file" name="file" required><br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-success" value="Subir Archivo">
</form>
```

Comment: NO entiendo que quieres hacer, ¿Quieres que no tenga el texto pero a la vez que lo muestre pero que no esté a la derecha?

Comment: Correcto, no encuentro como quitar solo ese texto, o moverlo a una ubicación más acorde... que raro, si entendiste jaja

Comment: Aqui tienes una opcion: https://www.espai.es/blog/2020/09/personalizar-el-aspecto-del-elemento-input-de-tipo-file/   yo lo que tambien hago es crear cualquier elemento que me guste y bindearlo al input file para que al hacer click sobre ese elemento dispare el input. Obviamente el input lo pongo display none

Comment: @HernánGarcia como haces ese bindeo ? Puedes agregarlo como respuesta ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Las dos soluciones que aporto en esta respuesta son una mezcla de distintas fuentes que he encontrado. Ambas son muy parecidas, y todo es personalizable y se puede adaptar a lo que se necesite mediante clases CSS, estilos online, etc.

La diferencia entre ambas soluciones es el lugar donde se puede mostrar el nombre de archivo a subir:

1. En el propio botón de `Seleccionar archivo`
2. Debajo del botón de `Seleccionar archivo`

Los trucos comunes usados en ambas soluciones son:

1. Esconder el `input type="file"` con una clase CSS o bien, como en el ejemplo, con un `style="display:none;"`
2. Crear una nueva etiqueta `label` que haga de disparador del **input** gracias a su atributo `for=`, el cual apunta al `id` del **input** que hemos escondido en el punto 1.
3. Encerrar el **label** en un `<button></button>` para que se muestre como tal.
4. Dentro del `<label></label>` agregar el texto a mostrar en el botón

### 1 - En el propio botón de `Seleccionar archivo`

En este caso, gracias al `id` agregado al **label**, luego lo capturamos en javascript con [getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) para cambiar su propiedad [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) cuando se elija un archivo, gracias a la escucha del evento [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) mediante [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), o bien dejamos el texto original `Selecciona un archivo`.

A continuación el código de esta solución:

```js
var inputArchivo = document.getElementById('inputarchivo');
inputArchivo.addEventListener("change", function() {
  let nombreArchivo = this.files[0].name;
  let labelArchivo = document.getElementById('labelarchivo');
  if (this.value != "") {
    labelArchivo.innerHTML = nombreArchivo;
  } else {
    labelArchivo.innerHTML = 'Selecciona un archivo'
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="subirArchivo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Subir un Archivo:<br><br>
  <input type="file" id="inputarchivo" name="file" style="display: none;" required><br>
  <button><label for="inputarchivo" id="labelarchivo">Selecciona un archivo</label></button>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-success" value="Subir Archivo">
</form>
```

### 2 - Debajo del botón de `Seleccionar archivo`

En este caso agregamos un `div` vacio (con su propio id) donde queramos, que después mostrará el nombre del archivo seleccionado. Y mediante las mismas funciones y técnicas descritas en el caso anterior, en javascript detectamos cualquier cambio en el **input** y ponemos en el **div** el nombre de archivo, o bien lo dejamos en blanco.

```js
var inputArchivo = document.getElementById('inputarchivo');
inputArchivo.addEventListener("change", function() {
  let nombreArchivo = this.files[0].name;
  let archivoSeleccionado = document.getElementById('archivoseleccionado');
  if (this.value != "") {
    archivoSeleccionado.innerHTML = nombreArchivo
  } else {
    archivoSeleccionado.innerHTML = ''
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="subirArchivo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Subir un Archivo:<br><br>
  <input type="file" id="inputarchivo" name="file" style="display: none;" required><br>
  <button><label for="inputarchivo">Selecciona un archivo</label></button>
  <div id="archivoseleccionado"></div>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-success" value="Subir Archivo">
</form>
```

Como se puede apreciar las diferencias son mínimas, pero he decidido exponerlo así finalmente porque el OP lo habia preguntado en los comentarios de esta respuesta, y particularmente yo prefería la opción del `div` (fue mi primera respuesta) porque sería una mejor solución en caso de un input con el atributo **multiple** con varios archivos.

Comment: Esta perfect, solo una duda, hay modo de meter el nombre del archivo en el texto del boton ?? Como mencione en el comentario, que vaya cambiando una vez elegido o no el archivo ?

Comment: Hecho, he agregado un id al label, que luego he capturado con getElementById() en el script para cambiar su innerHTML cuando elijas un archivo.

Comment: Se podría cambiar el label por un span? Me dice que no se puede usar label dentro de un botón.

Comment: @Luis ¿y el span te dice que si?  Plantéalo como una nueva pregunta pegando el caso de estos dos que estés intentando usar, y a ver si alguien te puede ayudar (seguramente con javascript se podria disparar con un trigger esa acción, pero sinceramente, ahora no dispongo de tiempo para probarlo ni ayudarte... quizás otro dia, pero en una nueva pregunta, no aquí)

Comment: Entiendo, gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui lo tienes:
HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="" id="input-file" style="display: none;">
 <button id="mi-boton">Mi Boton que activa el input file</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
let $miBoton = document.getElementById('mi-boton')

  $miBoton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   e.target.previousElementSibling.click()
  })
```

Funciona de la siguiente manera: pongo el boton que quiero que actue como input file a la escucha del evento click. y le hago un bindeo de la funcion click() de su elemento hermano previo (previusElementSibling). Luego ocultas el input file y listo. Saludos!!

Para que tengas el nombre del archivo que elegiste en el boton agrega estas lineas:

```
let $inputFile = document.getElementById('input-file') //debajo del $miBoton

$inputFile.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
   console.log(e.target.files[0].name);
   $miBoton.innerHTML = e.target.files[0].name
  })
```

Comment: Me genera un error al probarlo: https://jsfiddle.net/pw3an4rb/

Comment: eso no es por el bindeo, tienes un problema con el form (error 405) prueba a sacar el action, em method y el enctype y veras como funciona

Comment: Pero es todo parte del form...

Comment: Mi ejemplo funciona, lo puedes probar en un HTML por separado

Comment: Entonces pareciera estar lanzando el form antes de tiempo

Comment: No lo creo. De todos modos si te sirvio la opcion de masterguru no le demos mas vueltas

Comment: No logre ver que estaba mal en mi caso de todos modos, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Me funcionó perfecto, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

La manera más simple es con la propiedad **transparent** de css:

```
<input type="file" id="miArchivo" style="color: transparent"/>
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer].